# Configuration of 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons in content app dialog in Magnolia CMS

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

I am developing content app in magnolia and don't understand why 'Save' and 'Cancel' buttons in edit dialog don't display on first content item. On other items they are displayed.

First item:
[image]

And on other items:
[image]

Did I miss something or make some mistake in configuration? Please help.

Comment: Double check items are of a same type (export and check the node type).
  Are the actions in the dialog default ones or did you choose custom implementation? If the latter, there might be error when initialising action class. You should see more details in the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID for this item without buttons was returned in method `getDefaultItemId()` in container. When I changed this method in container to return `null`, buttons became available on this item.
Don't know why this behave in that way.